# How to find a normal vector to a surface at a given point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Suppose we define a curve $C$ by letting $C$ be the intersection of the unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=x$ that takes place for $z>0$.

Now I want to use Stoke's theorem to be able to compute a line integral around $C$ and as such I will need to find a unit normal vector to any point in the interior of $C$ this region we can call $S$.

I'm really struggling on how to find a unit normal vector for $S$ so that I can calculate:

$$\iint_S~(\nabla \times \vec{F})~\hat{n}~dS$$

I have got a parametrization for the curve $S$ but I don't really know if that will be of any use.

Comment: Note that Stokes's theorem says $C$ can be *any* surface having your curve as its boundary. The trick is to pick a *nice* surface that will make the flux of the curl easy to calculate. In this case, here's a hint: your curve lies on the surface $x+z^2=1$. (Note also that it's strange to denote a surface by $C$. Most people would call the *curve* $C$ and think of it as $\partial S$ for some surface $S$.)

Comment: Okay noted. I still don't understand your hint, sorry.

Comment: sorry, I misread what you're trying to do. My point is that the phrase "interior of $C$" makes no sense. There are infinitely many surfaces having the curve as its boundary. You need to choose one such surface that has easy normals to calculate. The easiest surface is probably the top part of the cylinder, lying above the sphere; the normal to the cylinder is easy. But you can choose any surface, such as the portion of the sphere enclosed by your curve. That normal is also easy to write down, but it may be hard to calculate with.

Comment: So the normal for the top of the cylinder (with the curve as its boundary) would be $(0,0,1)$ and we could find instead the normal for the sphere (with the curve as its boundary) as the gradient of $x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$ but  this is harder to work with is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This results in an interesting curve:

[image: The Sitation]

One surface $S$ with $\partial S = C$ is that bit of the cylinder sticking out of the unit sphere. It has easy normal vectors as well.

Another choice is the part of the unit sphere within the cylinder.

Comment: So a unit normal vector would be $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: For the top part. Otherwise it is the cylinder coordinates unit vector $e_r$. For the unit surface part it would by spherical coordinates unit vector $e_r$, thus different at any point on the surface. (Btw: both translated to $(0.5, 0, 0)$ as center)

Comment: but to use Stoke's theorem to take the line integral wouldn't it make sense to just consider the top of the cylinder with the curve we care about as it's boundary thus the unit normal is $(0,0,1)$ and easy to compute with?

Comment: I would have to think how to evaluate the surface integral. I believe it was the projection down to the $x$-$y$ plane times some factor maybe. It could be that only the top part of $S$ contributes to the integral and not the side part.

Answer (score 1):

A vector normal to the surface of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$,
$<x,y,z>$ would do it.

Or $<x/z, y/z, 1>$, or $<x/(1-x^2+y^2)^{1/2} , y/(1-x^2-y^2)^{1/2}, 1)$

$<-\partial z/\partial z,-\partial z/\partial y,1>$ is a generic approach for any surface in Cartesian coordinates.

Asked to provide more information...

It is high-school geometry that a vector from the center of a sphere will be normal to the surface. So, $<x,y,z>$ jumps out as a quick go-to...

$<x/z, y/z, 1>$ is nice because then a square unit in the x,y plane corresponds to the sq units above it.

But, if you are going to integrate in terms of $x$ and $y$ then it is handy to replace any $z$ terms as functions of $x,y$

To find the vector perpendicular to a more complicate surface... F(x,y,z) = K,

$\nabla F = <\partial F/\partial x,\partial F/\partial y,\partial F/\partial z>$ will be perpendicular to the surface.

If you can parameterize your surface in terms of $u$ and $v$ then:
$\partial S = <\partial x/\partial u,\partial y/\partial u,\partial z/\partial u>\times<\partial x/\partial v,\partial y/\partial v,\partial z/\partial v>$

and finally, you can use the existing $x,y$ that you already as your parameters.

$\partial S = <\partial x/\partial x,\partial y/\partial x,\partial z/\partial x>\times<\partial x/\partial y,\partial y/\partial y,\partial z/\partial y>$
which equals $<1,0,\partial z/\partial x>\times<0,1,\partial z/\partial y> = <-\partial z/\partial y,-\partial z/\partial y,1>$

Hope this helps

Comment: Would you please explain instead of just quoting the answer?

Comment: More detail provided.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when doing this you solve for $\hat{n}\cdot dS$ all at once rather than just the normal vector. When doing this there are a few ways.
**If You Know A Normal Vector**
Say you already know a normal vector to the surface, $\vec{N}$. Then
$$\hat{n}\cdot dS=\pm\frac{\vec{N}}{\vec{N}\cdot \hat{k}}$$
where the $\pm$ changes based on how you orient the surface.
**Using the Gradient**
You may have just thought the last method was counter intuitive, but you do know a normal vector to the surface! Say you have a function $g(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z)$, change it to the form $F(x,y,z)=c$ where $c$ is a constant. Then you are just looking at a level curve for the function $F$, and remember that gradients are always normal to level curves, so
$$\hat{n}\cdot dS=\pm\frac{\nabla F}{F_z}$$

**You Have an Explicit Function for Z**
Another common case would be if you were to be given the surface in the form $z=f(x,y,z)$. Then
$$\hat{n}\cdot dS=\pm<-z_x,-z_y,1>$$
**You Have The Parametrization of the Surface**
There is one last way that I know of that is for if you're given the parametrization of the function. Say the surface $S$ is defined by
$$S:\begin{cases}
x=x(u,v) \\
y=y(u,v) \\
z=z(u,v)
\end{cases}$$
Or in position vector notation we have the position vector,
$$\vec{r}=<x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)>$$
Then
$$\hat{n}\cdot dS=\pm\left(\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial v}\right)\text{d}u\text{d}v$$

Answer (score 0):

This surface is called [Viviani's window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_curve).

There are different ways of dealing with this. The best option, I believe, is to parametrize it in cartesian coordinates:
$$
x=x,\quad y=y, \quad z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},\quad (x,y)\in D
$$
with
$$
D=\{(x,y)\;|\;x^2+y^2\le x \}
$$
This way
$$
\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\iint_S \nabla\times \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}
=\iint_D \nabla\times \vec{F}(x,y)\cdot \vec{r}_x\times\vec{r}_y\; dA
$$
This is where parametrizing in cartesian coordinates is handy: computing the normal vector (which is what you asked for)  $\vec{r}_x\times\vec{r}_y$ is always very simple as you have $1$'s and $0$'s in your vectors:
$$
\vec{r}_x\times\vec{r}_y = 
(1,0,\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}})\times 
(0,1,\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}})
=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},1)
$$

You end up with 
$$
\iint_D \nabla\times \vec{F}(x,y)\cdot \vec{r}_x\times\vec{r}_y\; dA=\iint_D f(x,y)\; dA
$$
and from there a switch to polar coordinates and you are done:
$$
D=\{(r,\theta)\;|\; -\pi/2\le \theta \le \pi/2, 0\le r\le \cos{\theta} \}
$$